# Template classes in c++, list example

Tags: c++, list, templates

i'm trying to make a template class for a list in c++. This is something new for me, and i'm stuck. I've written add(T item) method and write() to write whole list on console, but i have random int as output.

Here's my code, if someone could tell me where my mistake is, i will be grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class Node {
private:
    Node<T> * next;
    Node<T> * prev;
    T key;
public:
    Node(T k) {
    next =(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    prev = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    key = k;
}
Node(T * n, T * p, T k) {
    next = n;
    prev = p;
    key = k;
}
void setNext(Node<T> * n) {
    next = n;
}
void setPrev(Node<T> * p) {
    prev = p;
}
void show() {
    cout << "key= " << key << endl;
}
};
template <class T> class List {
private:
    Node<T> * head;
    Node<T> * tail;
public:
    List() {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    cout << "list created!" << endl;
}
void add(T item) {
    Node<T> node(item);
    node.setNext(head);
    node.setPrev(nullptr);
    if (head != nullptr)
        head = &node;
    else {
        tail = &node;
    }
    head = &node;
}
void write() {
    head->show();
}
};

int main()
{
    List<int> lista;
    lista.add(8);
    lista.write();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ - in this case it's even completely wrong and invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: `next =(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));` what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: This is strange, why would you allocate dynamically the prev and next pointers, but not the actual node? It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add()` add a pointer to a `Note<T>` (`node`) in the list; but `node` is destroied when `add()` ends the execution.

So, when you call `write()`, that use `show()`, the pointed memory in undefined (random value).

To avoid this problem, you have to allocate the variable (with `new`! avoid `malloc()` with classes), so

```
Node<T> * nodePnt = new Node<T>(item);
```

and

```
head = nodePnt;

tail = nodePnt;
```

But remeber to delete it.

Comment: Any tip, how to make it properly?

Comment: @Karol.T - tip added.

Comment: Thanks for helping.